# How do I install LogZilla NEO on CoreOS?

Tags: coreos

When I try to install [LogZilla NEO](https://www.logzilla.net/download.html#header4-oz) (docker based) on CoreOS, I get:

```
docker run logzilla/kickstart -p >/usr/bin/logzilla; chmod 755 /usr/bin/logzilla; logzilla install
-bash: /usr/bin/logzilla: Read-only file system
chmod: cannot access '/usr/bin/logzilla': No such file or directory
-bash: logzilla: command not found
```

I found this: https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/sdk-disk-partitions.html
But am not sure if LogZilla has to be put in `/usr/bin`?

Comment: I can't create a tag for `logzilla` (something about reputation), can someone please add that tag?

Comment: Sorry, doesn't look like I have this ability either. Hopefully a moderator will add the tag for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Stackoverflow :)

The path to the LogZilla binary doesn't matter. In CoreOS, you can make a directory on the server where it is writeable, like `/opt/bin`.

So just use the following command:

`mkdir -p /opt/bin/; \
 docker run logzilla/kickstart -p >/opt/bin/logzilla; \
 chmod 755 /opt/bin/logzilla; \
 logzilla install`

Side note: The default ports used to map syslog and http in the LogZilla docker install are 32514, 32601, and 3280 (done intentionally so as not to try and use already-taken ports). But if you are certain the standard syslog/http ports are not in use on the host, you can set this during install, like so:

`logzilla install \
 --syslog-port-mapping=tcp/514:514,udp/514:514,tcp/601:601  \
 --http-port-mapping=tcp/80:80`

Update:
The install process is now much easier. Just use:

`curl -fsSL https://logzilla.sh | bash`